# How do you use guards(1) with quilt(1)

Tags: patch, guard, quilt

One of the ancillary tools bundled with `quilt` is `guards`, which processes a list of guards and a configuration file matching guards and files, and outputs a list of files whose guard specifications match the provided guards.

However I can't figure how they're supposed to fit together: quilt(1) doesn't show any way to invoke a command to generate series files, I didn't find examples in the mans or the working copy, and the internets are less than helpful (all the hits talk about bedding).

I feel like `guard` has to be manually invoked whenever its "dependencies" change and the series file overwritten, is that the case? If so, how is data fed back the other way around e.g. when adding a new patch to the series, does it have to be manually synchronised to the guard file?

Background: a few years back I used mq quite a bit, but it integrates guards natively so the synchronisation back and forth is not an issue at all.